# Wildcard expansion - searching for one in a set of possibilities

Tags: bash

I could have sworn you could do the following:

```
ls *.{java, cpp}
```

but that does not seem to work.  I know this answer is probably on the site somewhere but I couldn't find it via search.

For instance, if I want to be able to use the globbing with a find command, I would want to do something like

```
find . -name "*.{java,cpp}" | xargs grep -n 'TODO'
```

Is this possible without resorting to using the -o binary operator?

Comment: Funny, that find command doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that you are seeing an error message such as this:

> ls: cannot access *.{java: No such file or directory
>   ls: cannot access ,cpp}: No such file or directory

If that's the case, it's because of the space after the comma. Leave it out:

```
ls *.{java,cpp}
```

For future reference, it is more helpful to post error messages than to say "it's not working" (please don't take this personally. It's meant for everyone to see. I even do it <s>sometimes</s>too often).

Comment: I knew I was being stupid and that it had worked at some point in the past.  You're right, it was the silly space I had put in there.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`ls *.{java,cpp}` works just fine for me in bash...:

```
$ ls *.{java,cpp}
a.cpp       ope.cpp     sc.cpp      weso.cpp
helo.java   qtt.cpp     srcs.cpp
```

Are you *sure* it's not working for you...?

`find` is different, but

```
find -E . -regex '.*\.(java|cpp)'
```

should do what you want (in some versions you may not need the `-E` or you may need a `-regextype` option there instead, "man find" on your specific system to find out).

Comment: My `find` doesn't know about `-E` so I have to escape the parentheses and pipe character: `find  . -regex '.*\(java\|cpp\)'` or use the `-regextype` option with one of these arguments: posix-awk, posix-egrep or posix-extended.

Comment: Yep, I did mention that some versions (e.g. GNU I believe) want -regextype, others (e.g. BSD I believe) what -E instead.

Answer (score 0):

But this *does* work in Bash:

```
$ ls
a.h  a.s  main.cpp  main.s
$ ls *.{cpp,h}
a.h  main.cpp
```

Are you *sure* you're in Bash?  If you are, maybe an alias is causing the issue: try `/bin/ls *.{java,cpp}` to make sure you don't call the aliased `ls`.

Or, just take out the spaces in your list inside the `{}` -- the space *will* cause an error because Bash will see `*.{java,` as one argument to `ls`, and it will see `cpp}` as a second argument.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example, this may also do what you want

```
grep -rn TODO . --include '*.java' --include '*.cpp'
```